# Cannot Instantiate class error - Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, pageobjects

I am facing this 'Cannot insantiate class' error on running one of my test cases in selenium webdriver using java.

Below is the class of the functionality of the test,

```
package Pages;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import Lib.lib;

public class KnowledgeBase extends lib{

    By sortBylink = By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/featured-studies-grid/div[2]/featured-studies-toolbar/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div");
    By featuredOption = By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/featured-studies-grid/div[2]/featured-studies-toolbar/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]");
    By mostRcnt = By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/featured-studies-grid/div[2]/featured-studies-toolbar/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/li[2]");

    String featOption = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/featured-studies-grid/div[2]/featured-studies-toolbar/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]")).getText();

    String mostRecent = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/featured-studies-grid/div[2]/featured-studies-toolbar/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/li[2]")).getText();

    public void initSBy() throws Exception
    {
        driver.findElement(sortBylink).click();
        Thread.sleep(1500);
    }

    public void selectfO() throws Exception
    {
        driver.findElement(featuredOption).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

    public void selectMr() throws Exception
    {
        driver.findElement(mostRcnt).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

    public void sortBy(String sProp) throws Exception
    {
        this.initSBy();

        if (sProp == featOption) {

            this.selectfO();

        }

        else if (sProp == mostRecent){

            this.selectMr();
        }

        else {

            System.out.println("Incorrect option. Test failed.");
        }
    }


}
```

Below is my Test Case Class

```
package TestCases;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import Lib.lib;
import Pages.KnowledgeBase;
import Pages.LoginPage;

public class sortingTextKB extends lib {

    LoginPage uLogin = new LoginPage();
    KnowledgeBase sortObj = new KnowledgeBase();

    //Logging In
    @Test (priority = 1)
    public void loggingIn() throws Exception
    {
        uLogin.loginToKB("uzii@test.com", "uziiiii");
    }

    //Sorting
    @Test (priority = 2)
    public void sortIn() throws Exception
    {
        sortObj.sortBy("Most Recent");
    }

}
```

Below is my Lib class, that contains the chrome driver configuration

```
package Lib;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;

public class lib {

    protected static WebDriver driver = null;

    @BeforeTest
    public void chrome_extension()
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("http://www.testsite.com");
    }


    @AfterTest
    public void quit()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

When I run my test case class, I am getting the following error,

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class TestCases.sortingTextKB
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:38)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:387)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:299)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:110)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:186)
    at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.<init>(TestNGClassFinder.java:120)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:409)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:235)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:205)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:160)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG.java:141)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG.java:271)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:561)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:157)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1299)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1286)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:29)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Pages.KnowledgeBase.<init>(KnowledgeBase.java:22)
    at TestCases.sortingTextKB.<init>(sortingTextKB.java:12)
    ... 26 more
```

Following is the 22 line of KnowledgeBase class,

```
String featOption = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/featured-studies-grid/div[2]/featured-studies-toolbar/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]")).getText();
```

Please let me know why I am facing this 'cannot instantiate class' error. Thanks

Comment: You know what line is causing the issue... what have you tried to solve it?

Comment: @JeffC I am unable to figure out why is this not instantiating the class. If I dont use above line 22 , then it might work, but I need to get the text, so I can compare it with the one I give at run time.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException` have you tried googling what a `NullPointerException` is? Then look at line 22 and do some troubleshooting. Post the code that you tried and what didn't work.

Comment: @JeffC the case here is that, in my KnowledgeBase class in the function sortBy(String sProp), if I give hard coded values for "sProp" inside 'if statements' then my case is working fine, but if i pass the string in them using driver.find....getText(); statement then I am getting cannot instantiate class error. I dont know what is the issue with that if I pass a string variable in if statements.

Comment: driver just doesn't get initialized maybe your `@BeforeTest
    public void chrome_extension()` does not get executed

Comment: @ACV But if I pass hard coded values like this:
if (sProp == "Most Recent")
{
      code here....
}

In this case , the driver gets initialized. The issue is being the String command where I am getting the text of the options and passing it as a string to verify with the user's option.

Comment: have you checked that this path exists `"html/body/div[1]/featured-studies-grid/div[2]/featured-studies-toolbar/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]"` ?

Comment: @ACV Yes, the path exists, and I verified it as well, as you can see 'featuredOption' and 'mostRcnt' buttons definition have the same xpaths

Answer (score 1):

You can download "chromedriver.exe" then add this to your project. You no need to use this `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");`. You can use `ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`
If still get error, please provide permission for the file "chromedrive.exe".

Answer (score 0):

You should try instantiating your object. This should remove the error being presented.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to like this , may be it works.

```
@Test (priority = 2)
    public void sortIn() throws Exception
    { `enter code here
        sortObj = new KnowledgeBase();
        sortObj.sortBy("Most Recent");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below.
i created the WebDriver object outside @Test annotation and instantiated it in @Test as.

```
public class TestNGClass
{
    WebDriver driver;
    public String baseUrl = "http://newtours.demoaut.com/"; 
    @Test
    public void verifyHomepageTitle()
    {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        String expectedTitle = "Welcome: Mercury Tours";
        String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
        Assert.assertEquals(actualTitle, expectedTitle);
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```